# What is the advantage of using Sandbox mode in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, sandbox

I understand that sandbox mode stops expressions that Microsoft considers 'unsafe.' These expressions can be wrapped in VBA code to circumvent the sandbox. But what is the advantage? Is it merely that you can provide some sort of validation within the code? I am specifically talking about the expression `Environ("username")`.

I have set up a test application that used the above expression in a control, which is explicitly blocked when sandbox mode is on, however, I have wrapped the expression in VBA code as well inside a module - which is not affected by VBA.

Is the VBA code safer to use than the control expression? I am having trouble finding how I would exploit an expression in a control, and is it any safer to use the VBA code? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox mode is a general safety measure geared toward the Jet/ACE engine and preventing applications, including Access and any other app using the engine for reading/writing to MDB and ACCDB databases (and also Excel files), from using Jet/ACE as a means to run unsafe expressions.

For instance, access to environment variables could allow sensitive information (like the username) to be read and others (like the PATH) to be changed.

Sandbox mode is a default security measure that prevents **all** applications that use the Jet/ACE database engine from running these arbitrary, and potentially dangerous, commands.

#### Trust vs sandbox

Note that sandbox mode is different from *Trust*: the sandbox is only concerned with items that are interpreted through the Jet/Ace database engine, not VBA.

Trust on the other hand will ensure that Access applications are always disabled by default and will thus disable ActiveX, VBA, etc unless that application is running from a Trusted Location (folder).

When you open a database outside of a Trusted location (for instance one downloaded from the internet in your `Download` folder or on your Desktop) it will have a big yellow warning saying that all active content has been disabled.
The user would need to click on that button to enable temporary the application after he/she has assessed the security risk.

So Trust is just about enabling/disabling of active content in an Application. Sandbox is an additional (an independent) layer that is always on by default and prevents 'dangerous' operations from being run through the database engine.

#### Bypassing the sandbox

Most Trusted applications will have no need to get outside of the sandbox.

If you need to access some sensitive operations, once your application is Trusted, you can use VBA instead.
It's OK because the user would have explicitly allowed it, either by clicking the warning when they opened the application or by running it from a registered Trusted location.

If an application really needs to use run outside the sandbox to execute unsafe expressions you must first change the `SandboxMode` registry key and then run your application from a Trusted location (or have your application digitally signed).

To change the registry key, the user account would need to be able to modify it (normal users only have read access to it).

So the thinking is that to disable sandbox mode, you need to log in as Administrator of the machine and modify that registry key. It's not something you can do by accident!

#### Registry

If you really want to disable Sandbox mode (you probably shouldn't) you will find the `SandboxMode` key under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines` (or `\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines` on 64 bit OS running 32 bit Office) and the valid values for key are:

- 0 Sandbox mode is disabled at all times.
- 1 Sandbox mode is used for Access, but not for non-Access programs.
- 2 Sandbox mode is used for non-Access programs, but not for Access.
- 3 Sandbox mode is used at all times. This is the default value, set when you install Access.

#### Conclusion

I think the main thinking there was to ensure a set of safe default in layers:

- a vanilla install of Office would ensure that you can't open and run unsafe code by default (the database isn't Trusted)
- the sandbox mode prevents apps (including Access) from running unsafe commands throught the Jet/Ace database Engine in all cases.
- you still have the flexibility you need, but it requires jumping through few determinate hoops to work properly (modify the registry as administrator). Something most applications should shy away from.

It's probably that Microsoft saw this as a way to push developers to only use safe expressions when using the database engine by making it difficult to run unsafe commands.